# Is it acceptable to use a shared singelton class to communicate between an activity and a foreground service?

Tags: android, service, android-activity

I have a foreground service that is processing gps location from the location manager. I am storing these in a generic "location controller" singleton. Currently my activity is also accessing this class. Is this acceptable? It seems more efficient then using handler messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing really wrong with it, so long as you are *very* sure that you are not going to introduce any memory leaks. Other existing message bus solutions, like `LocalBroadcastManager` (from the Android Support Library), [Otto](http://square.github.com/otto/), and kin use a singleton behind the scenes.

I would recommend that you use `LocalBroadcastManager` or Otto or something than rolling your own, just because they are better supported and tested.
T

Comment: Agreed. Singletons are always an option but almost never the optimal one.

Answer (score 0):

For this particular case, since you expect frequent updates of the location that should be communicated to the `activity`; I would say `bind` to the location service might be a more appropriate solution.

So basically, in your activity `onResume` you `bind` to the service and pass a `listener` object to the `service` that will be called whenever a location update exists. Also, you should `unbind` with the service in `onPause`.

Just be aware to *start* the service **before** binding so it keeps running if the activity is no longer in the foreground.

I have very similar case and this solution works very well and it gives you the ability to add a method in the `service` like `getLastLocation()` which can be invoked from the activity on demand.